# converting a .wma to .flac using PHP? possible?

Tags: linux, wma, flac

I have a linux server, I am looking to convert a .wma file to .flac file 16k

Is there a way I can do this using a PHP Script to control the server?

I was thinking .wma to .wav then .flac would be easier, but not sure how...

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Nearly *everything* is possible. Have you at least done some research?

Comment: I have indeed. I cant find any thing. I can only find software to install, not something I can use on my server?

Comment: Find some batch converter and invoke it from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the command line through PHP so that it just works as a safe interface to remote users.

Keeping that in mind you can use the ffmpeg library to go right from .wma to .flac using:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.wma -acodec flac -aq 100 sample.flac
```

You'll want to have something to manage file names and getting/serving the files, etc but that doesn't seem to be the hurdle in this case.